# Unable to run phonegap iOS app

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode4, cordova-3

I am unable to 'run' phonegap ios hello world app. Same approach on windows machine with android SDK worked. I've been googling this for a while but didn't found anything helpful. Any thoughts what may error I am getting mean?

Configuration:

> phonegap -v: 3.4.0-0.19.7
>
> cordova -v: 3.4.0-0.1.3
>
> Mac OS X: 10.7.5 (unupgradable - Intel GMA X3100)
>
> Xcode: 4.6.3

approach:

```
~: phonegap create hello
~: cd hello
~: phonegap run ios
...
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

2014-03-16 18:24:17.091 ios-sim[6863:707] stderrPath: /Users/username/git/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2014-03-16 18:24:17.096 ios-sim[6863:707] stdoutPath: /Users/username/git/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2014-03-16 18:24:17.110 ios-sim[6863:707] Error loading /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/DVTFoundation:  dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/DVTFoundation, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/DVTFoundation: GC capability mismatch
Unable to dvtFoundationBundle. Error: 
   [error] /Users/username/git/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved that issue by downgrading to ios-sim 1.8.2

```
npm uninstall -g ios-sim
brew uninstall ios-sim
npm install -g ios-sim@~1.8
```

Comment: no i have [ios-sim --version 1.9.0] and i have the same error

Comment: I wrote that I needed to downgrade to 1.8. Your version [1.9] was the problem. See `npm install -g ios-sim@~1.8`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. I had installed ios-sim using npm. Try uninstalling ios-sim and install it using brew.

```
npm uninstall -g ios-sim

brew install ios-sim
```

Comment: ios-sim from brew give the latest version, only. So it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by (1)brew uninstalling the 1.9 version and then 
                 (2) brew install the 1.8 version

This link explains the version change in brew: https://coderwall.com/p/lqphzg

Comment: Add more explanation to your answer. Because link only answers will expire if the link is expired.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by upgrading Xcode from 4.x.x to the latest (5.1.1). Then I reinstalled ios-sim using MacPorts. Then "phonegap run ios" succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange issue.

In my case, I solved this by running the project in Xcode on a simulator (found at platforms/ios/*.xcodeproj). When I went back to phonegap the problem was resolved.